# A different approach to comparing integers with strings in java?

Tags: java

I have a program that goes through each string in a text file. I want to compare these strings to an "ID" number that i have. In this case im using Integer.parseInt() which throws a NumberFormatException when the string im comparing has characters in it. Is there another way I can compare an integer with strings without running into this error?

```
            int num;
            int ID = 354;
            Scanner sc2 = null;

            try {
                sc2 = new Scanner(new File("Database.txt"));
            } 
            catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();  
            }
            while (sc2.hasNextLine()) 
            {
                Scanner s2 = new Scanner(sc2.nextLine());
                while (s2.hasNext()) 
                {
                    String s = s2.next();
                    System.out.println(s);
                    num = Integer.parseInt(s);
                    if(num == ID)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Success.");
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: You could either turn `ID` into a String and use `equals()` (inefficient, but less code), or you could catch the NumberFormatException and `continue` the while loop (ignoring lines that can't be parsed as integers)

Comment: @VivekChavda Yes, I guess catching exceptions all the time is much better than creating Strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either turn `ID` into a String and use `equals()` (inefficient, but less code), or you could catch the NumberFormatException and `continue` the while loop (ignoring lines that can't be parsed as integers)

Comment: I attempted your second suggestions and it works great. Thanks.